# Проверить наличие команды setserial

Tags: linux, bash

Нужно проверить, что на компе работает команда setserial.

Делаю так

```
setser=$(setserial -g /dev/ttyS[0-9] | grep -v unknown)
if $setser = '-sh: setserial: not found'
    then
        echo NOT AVAILABLE
    else
        echo OK
    fi
```

Выводит:

```
$ ./setser.sh
./setser.sh: line 1: setserial: not found
./setser.sh: line 11: =: not found
OK
```

Что не так?

В итоге пока нашел такой вариант

```
FILE=/usr/local/bin/setserial
if [ -f $FILE ]; then
   echo "Command Exists"
else
   echo "Command Does Not Exist"
fi
```

Comment: *Что не так?* — не найдена программа `setserial`.

Comment: Да. Но нашел альтернативный вариант

Answer (score 2, accepted):

проверить доступность той или иной программы можно [разными способами](https://stackoverflow.com/q/592620/4827341).

например, можно воспользоваться описанной в стандарте *posix* встроенной командой оболочки [`command`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/command.html). например, так:

```
if command -v setserial >/dev/null 2>&1
then echo "существует"
else echo "не существует"
fi
```

Comment: Спасибо. Попробую тоже.

Comment: пардон, в ответе вместо setserial затесалось другое название, использованное мною для теста.

Answer (score 1):

1. > ./setser.sh: line 1: setserial: not found

   Прежде, чем пытаться выполнить утилиту `setserial`, можно проверить ее наличие в системе, это можно сделать разными способами. Например:

   ```
   setserial && echo "OK"
   ```

   Или так:

   ```
   command -v setserial && echo "OK"
   ```

   Или, если вы знаете путь, где находится утилита, можно сделать так:

   ```
   if test -f path/to/setserial; echo "OK"; fi
   ```
2. > if $setser = '-sh: setserial: not found'

   Для проверки условия, используйте утилиту `test` (`[`), например:

   ```
   if (test "$setser" = "some output"); then echo "OK"; fi
   ```
3. > .sh: line 1: setserial: not found

   Ну и, судя по номеру строки (**line 1**), вы забыли использовать *shebang*   , например:

   ```
    #!/bin/sh
   ```

Comment: по поводу `which`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/677212/4827341

Comment: @alexanderbarakin спасибо за информацию, до этого не задумывался над правильным использованием which в скриптах, о его выводе и прочем. Потому как не приходилось его использовать :)

Comment: Спасибо. Отлично описано.

Answer (score -2):

В итоге так выкрутился

```
FILE=/usr/local/bin/setserial
if [ -f $FILE ]; then
   echo "Command Exists"
else
   echo "Command Does Not Exist"
fi
```

Comment: искать программу по абсолютному пути — по-моему, малопродуктивно.

Comment: Согласен, просто в отсутствие способов воспользовался этим. А так то, что вы написали, очень хороший вариант.

Comment: возможно, лучше будет удалить этот ответ, а то его будут минусовать, как неудачный.