# Как узнать путь до исполняемого файла в Linux?

Tags: linux

Как в Linux узнать путь до исполняемого файла? В виндовс, например, на ярлыке или в bin/app.exe можно через свойство посмотреть

Интересуюсь с целью создавать *.desktop ярлыки для заполнениями ими рабочего стола , так как способ "добавить в избранное" мне не подходит и получается рабочий стол пустой

Comment: [дубликат](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/482710/178576)

Comment: Для  создания *.desktop нет необходимости указывать полный путь. Посмотрите примеры в /usr/share/applications

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Команда `which`. Например,

```
user@linux:~$ which java
```

Вывод:

```
/usr/bin/java
```

Comment: Я по факту могу найти приложение в диспетчере приложений, можно ли как-то оттуда взять этот путь? 
Или лучше и правильнее поискать путь к .exe в папках типа как в Windows --> C/Program FIles/app_folder/bin/app.exe    ?

Comment: В линуксе нет .exe, и бинарники могут быть в разных местах.

Comment: Ну и в линуксе есть примерно 10500 программ, которые можно назвать "диспетчер приложений"...

Comment: Внизу слева есть кнопка "Показать приложения", я про это имел в виду, оттуда бы как-то брать пути, там же ярлыки и их на рабочий стол хочу закидывать : )

Comment: @JaNix, какой у вас дистрибутив?

Comment: @eanmos Linux Ubuntu (Gnome -> без всяких разрешений, как скачал, не ставил всякие KDE) 20.04

Answer (score 2):

Если вы знаете имя исполняемого файла, который выполняется в текущий момент, то полный путь к исполняемому можно узнать вот так:

```
pgrep <exe_name> | while read pid; do echo -ne "$pid\t"; readlink -f /proc/$pid/exe; done
```

Например, вывод для исполняемого процесса `gopls` (сервер `go` для VS Code):

```
pgrep gopls | while read pid; do echo -ne "$pid\t"; readlink -f /proc/$pid/exe; done
30880   /mnt/drive2/home2/user/go/bin/gopls
```

Answer (score 1):

Набрав в командной строке

```
$ man whereis
```

Увидим:

*whereis  locates  the  binary,  source and manual files for the specified command names.  The supplied names are first stripped of leading pathname components and any (single) trailing extension of the form .ext (for example: .c) Prefixes of s.  resulting from use of source code control are also dealt with.  whereis then attempts to locate the desired program in the standard Linux places, and in the places specified by $PATH and $MANPATH.*